# How can I remove the headers that are exported along with data from the CSV file?

Tags: php, symfony4

I am working on CSV Export. This file is to be uploaded in ftp server. This is the code I am using to export. It is exporting but along with data it is exporting the header as well. I have added image below.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$date = $now->format('YmdHis');
$filename = $this->ftpOrderPath. "Order_$date.csv";

$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-type', 'text/csv');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $filename  . '";');
$response->sendHeaders();
$content = $response->setContent($content);


$this->defaultStorage->write($filename, $content);
```

[image]

Can anybody help me how can I remove those headers from my CSV ?

Comment: Looks as though you don't need to do anything with a `Response()` and just write the original value of `$content`.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes i got it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though it is just dumping the entire `Response` to the file as text.  So I would remove that part and just write the contents directly...

```
$now = new DateTime();
$date = $now->format('YmdHis');
$filename = $this->ftpOrderPath. "Order_$date.csv";
$this->defaultStorage->write($filename, $content);
```